# ¿Por qué se usa doble ii en un for?

Tags: javascript, variables, bucle-for

¿Para qué sirve el doble i (`ii`) en este `for`?

```
for (ii = 0; ii < data[i].foods.likes.length; ii++){
      htmlCadena += data[i].foods.likes[ii];
    }
```

El código completo pueden verlo en este video en el minuto 33:19 mas o menos:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rJesac0_Ftw

Comment: Es simplemente el nombre de una variable porque ya estan usando la variable i para otra cosa.

Comment: Lo mas probable es que se encuentre dentro de un for anidado, como dice @alanfcm la doble ii indica una variable diferente a i que puede estar en uso por otro for u otro valor.

Comment: La doble ii solamente hace referencia a un nombre de variable. Bien pudo llamarse `j` o `p`. En el ejemplo lo mas probable es que la variable `i` ya haya sido utilizada por lo que decidio utilizar `ii` en su lugar. Saludos!

Comment: Deberías declararla.. `for (let ii = 0;` o `for (var ii = 0;`  sino es global

Comment: Se puede usar cualquier nombre, lo recomendable no es usar ii, p o q, lo mejor es usar nombres con significado.

Answer (score 1):

## Respuesta corta

El uso de doble i (`ii`) ha sido una elección que ha realizado el autor del código.

## Respuesta extendida

No he visto el video referido. Quizás el autor indica sus motivos de usar ese nombre de variable.

En términos generales te podemos decir que comparado con otros lenguajes JavaScript es bastante laxo en muchas cosas cosas, incluyendo la forma de declarar variables y los nombres de las mismas. En ocasiones los programadores tienen total libertad de usar los nombres de variables que les plazca en otras ya sea por decisión propia o por algún tipo de obligación no pueden hacerlo.

Cabe destacar que existe lo que se conoce como "guías de estilo" las cuales son documentos en los que se han reunido reglas sobre cómo escribir código. Algunas incluyen reglas sobre los nombres a usar para las variables.

Cuando se escribe código profesionalmente es muy probable que el programador o alguien más utilice herramientas para verificar que se han seguido dichas reglas de alguna guía de estilo particular.